# how to show/hide msg dialog corecrtly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm trying to make a chat application, in the opening of just one dialog  msg, i can show/hide the dialog correctly, like the image below,[befor hide chat msg content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7u2G.png)  - [hide msg dialog content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4srCb.png) but when i try to open many dialog i have this probleme (like in the img) the header of the chat dialog not display in the bottom [multiple chat dialg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxbhq.png)
thank you .

```
<script>
    /*clicking on the head of msg_box for hide/show the content of the 
      msg_box*/
          $(document).on('click', '.show_hide_click', function()
          {
            var to_user_id = $(this).data('touserid');
            $('.show_hide_msg[data-touserid="'+to_user_id+'"]').slideToggle();
          });
</script>
<html>
    <ul id="list">
    <li class="mx-1 mt-3 msg_content " data-touserid="+to_user_id+" >
        <div class="head bg-success text-center  border-bottom border-secondary">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 bg-da py-1 show_hide_click" data-touserid="+to_user_id+">
                    <img src="avatar-teacher.png" alt="aa" style="height: 5.5vmi" class="mr-2">
                    <label for="">+to_user_name+</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-lg text-white fa-sm m-2 pt-2 hide_msg_content" data-touserid="+to_user_id+"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>                                                              
        </div>
        <div class="show_hide_msg" data-touserid="+to_user_id+">
            <div class="chat_history " id="chat_history_+to_user_id+" data-touserid="+to_user_id+">
                fetch_user_chat_history(to_user_id
            </div>
            <div class="body">

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea placeholder="Write msg..." style="overflow:hidderesize: none" name="chat_message_+to_user_id+" id="chat_message_+to_user_id+" class="form-control chat_message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-right form-group">
                            <a href="#" id="+to_user_id+" class=" send_chat">
                                <i class="m-2 fas fa-paper-plane"></i>  
                            </a>
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always post the relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript that you are working with in your question.

Comment: If you are having an issue with code, the code needs to be included in the question itself.  Pictures of code are not helpful.  Post the code, itself.

Comment: Include the code in the question, not the comments.  There is an edit button on the bottom left of the question.

Comment: Please don't add your code as a comment. Edit your question and add it there. Take a moment and examine the toolbar while you are editing your question. There is a button there to create a "snippet". That's where you can enter your code so that it can be executed.

Comment: sorry, i'm new , i put the code correctly now

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Edit the CSS attributes directly:

```
function toggleVisibility(elementID, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    $(elementID).attr("style", "display:block");
  } else {
    $(elementID).attr("style", "display:none");
  }
}
```

2) Ues jQuery's `toggleClass()`, which will add/remove a class from the element's classList (*depending on if it exists in the classList or not*) so you could have `.visible` and `.hidden` classes that are swapped without you having to worry about the state.

```
function toggleBtn(elementID){
  $(elementID).toggleClass('visible').toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it gives the same result, my problem is when i try to open manychat dialog, like the images above

Comment: the header of the chat dialog not displaying in the bottom

Comment: I would suggest having two CSS classes for the header (open & minimized) and the same for the body (open & minimized), with each class applying the appropriate CSS styling, and use `toggleClass()`  to swap between the two.

Comment: also you would want to have a separate Class to control the side by side stacking of the chat windows.